# Cysticercoids of Eucestoda

Tags: zoology, development

I have found the following pictures representing cysticercoids of Eucestoda.

If I correctly understand the right part of the picture, I would say that the development of the scolex is portrayed on the right, as the formation of what I think to be two acetabula shows. Nevertheless, with respect to the images on the left, it is totally unclear to me, since the text says nothing about it, what the structure that seems to be encapsulating the animal is.

[image]

I know that cysticercoids develops from an oncosphere, but I do not know whether that sort of capsule that seems to be enveloping the animal is a part of what was the oncosphere's tegument -the embrionophore- that it can have gone out of and is entering again...

Does anybody reading this question know more about it? I thank you very much for any answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the left part of the picture depicts 2 stages of the development of cysticercoid, while the right part shows the consecutive stages in the development of cysticercus. These two parts represent different species of tapeworms in the same stage of their developments.

Comment: To say the truth, the cysticercus is drawn in another picture elsewhere, while the legenda under this one says *cysticercoid*... As to that sort of tailed capsule which seems to envelopes the animal on the left, what is it? Thank you so much again!